# Conversion of std::string to c-string mosquitto

Tags: c++, linux, string, ascii, mosquitto

I'm using mosquitto to publish some message to a subscriber.

For subscriber I use:

mosquitto_sub -h host -t "new_topic" -q 0

Instead, for publish I develop a program that uses mosquittopp wrapper, but isn't relevant.

I send message using this method:

```
int MyClass::publish(const char* message) {
    return mosquittopp::publish(NULL, topic_, strlen(message),
            (uint8_t*) message, qos_);
}
....
MyClass publisher;
string s = base64_decode("LAAAtQ8AIXRpwoVyeMKodMK2wpPDscKBYcKDw6jCg8KAYWDDhjVCMQ==");
publisher.publish(s.c_str());
```

If I print s, I get:

```
,�!tirx¨t¶ñaèa`Æ5B1
```

And I think is ok.

But subscriber seems receiving only first char, in fact print only:

```
 ,
```

Any ideas?

## update

It was a [BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mosquitto/+bug/1247559) on version I used (1.3.1), fixed from version 1.3.4.

Comment: What did you expect `strlen` to do?

Comment: Don't add the word "[solved]" to the title. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. Feel free to post and accept your own answer if none of the existing ones resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The second character of the decoded string has the value zero. That's used to mark the end of a C-style string; so `strlen` will report a length of 1 upon finding a zero after one character.

If you want to use "strings" containing null characters, you can't use the C library's null-terminated string handling functions. I'd change `MyClass::publish` to work with a C++ string (or perhaps `std::vector<uint8_t>` so that it won't be mistaken for a printable string), so the length is available as `message.size()` whether or not it contains null characters.

Comment: uhm.. god tips.. so you modified mosquittopp wrapper or mosquitto library?

Comment: @Velthune: No, I've never heard of the library before. I'm just giving general advice for handling binary data.

Comment: what if I can't modify mosquitto?

Comment: @Velthune: I'm not suggesting you modify the library. I'm suggesting you modify `MyClass::publish`. (Sorry, I didn't notice that both functions had the same name, so my suggestion was ambiguous).

Comment: I would _definitely_ change `MyClass::publish`. There is no good reason at all for that to take a `const char*` .. especially without a length argument!

Comment: @Velthune: Yes, although the parameter type needs to be a reference, not a pointer, for that to compile.

Comment: my mistake.. doesn't work... for example if I have message={0x31, 0x31, 0x00, 0xB5, 0x0F}, subscriber receive only first two char (11)..